# MySQL - Select two columns as one based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

In the table above there is a column called `from_stop` and a column called `to_stop`.

I want to select all `from_stop` values where `from_timing` is equal to 'PTP' and select all `to_stop` values where `to_timing` is equal to 'PTP', **in a single column**.

So essentially I should have a column called `stop` that selects what I've said above.

I have made a few attempts but this query is baffling me because of poor relational set up, I am aware of that but this can't be changed.

Any ideas?

Example results:

`stop_column`
`1900HA030090`
`1900HA058450`

So essentially I have a column of results where the `from_timing` and `from_stop` are equal or  `to_timing` and `to_stop` are equal.

Comment: bit confused...mind posting what your expected results are from this example?  Are you simply trying to concatenate two columns from the same row in your output, or are you matching a to_stop record to a different from_stop record here?  Posting what you've tried will help as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT from_stop FROM <rel_name> WHERE from_timing = 'PTP'
UNION
SELECT to_stop FROM <rel_name> WHERE to_timing = 'PTP'
```

This will remove all duplicates, if you want to retain duplicates use UNION ALL instead